# Showing newlines in <p:terminal>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, terminal, newline

How can I show newlines in `<p:terminal>`?

The following string

```
Id     name         memory
1     process1      234lk
2     process2       456k
```

is shown as

```
Id     name         memory/1     process1     234lk/2     process2     456k
```

How can I show newlines?

Comment: Your initial formatting was quite strange. I hope that I've fixed it rightly, else just edit. Please read the Help section of the message editor to learn how to properly format messages here in Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well add some html to your response. If your returning a string format it with html tags in your case you can format it like this

```
<pre>Id     name         memory<br/>
1     process1      234lk<br/>
2     process2       456k<br/></pre>
```

And you've got the newlines in your terminal and your spaces are preserved.